# How to enable screen recording for DevOps? TestSettings issue

Tags: .net, selenium, devops, recording

I'm trying to set up screen recording for my local environment, and for running on a Release in Microsoft DevOps Pipelines. I've been trying a few different approaches that might conflict, but any help is appreciated.

I'm stuck here:
I cannot find the option to "Screen and Voice Record" within Test Settings.

[image: Location where I expected to find "Screen and voice recorder"]

This is my .runsettings file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
                <!--Video data collector was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
                <Configuration>
                    <!-- Set "sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase" to "false" to add video attachments to failed tests only -->
                    <MediaRecorder sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase="false"  xmlns="">
                        <ScreenCaptureVideo bitRate="512" frameRate="2" quality="20" />
                    </MediaRecorder>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Resources I used:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#capture-screenshot

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1959

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you need Visual Studio Profession/Enterprise. I have since upgraded and am now using this flawlessly.

Comment: I am having the same issue but I'm already registered with Visual Studio Professional